# How to prevent JSoup cleaner tampering the content

Tags: jsoup

I need JSoup to remove scripts from some HTML string, and using this snippet for that:

```
Document unsafeDoc = Jsoup.parse(unsafeHtml);
Document safeDoc = cleaner.clean(unsafeDoc);
OutputSettings o = safeDoc.outputSettings();
o.escapeMode(EscapeMode.xhtml);
return safeDoc.select("body").html();
```

But it is inserting extra space before `<br>` tags, converting " and ' to `&quot`; and `&apos;` etc., which I don't want. Could not find a way to achieve this. Would appreciate any help or recommendations of any other library than JSoup doing this.

Thanks,
Sanjay

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
safeDoc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);
```

I had the same problem and that fixed it.