# Jsoup - custom elements avoid formatting

Tags: java, jsoup

I am doing some processing with JSOUP (element removal), but I see some unwanted side effect. I have custom element `<my-element/>` and when I process it with JSOUP it becomes  `<my-element />`. So unwanted space is added at the end. I can deal with that, but it would ideal for me to avoid this.

My removal code looks like this:

```
Document html = Jsoup.parse(c);
Element toRemove = html.select(".to-remove").first();
if (toRemove != null) {
    toRemove.remove();
}
String result = html.outerHtml();
```

How can I configure JSOUP so it does not touch other than removed elements?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288324/how-to-prevent-jsoup-cleaner-tampering-the-content

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683018/jsoup-clean-without-adding-html-entities

Comment: thanks, will check them out.

Comment: @SusanMustafa your links helped, but I still have one more issue they don't solve. I have reformatted my question.